Bash script to start a session on screen and split terminal on startup
What I want basically looks like this (terminal split in 3 areas with screen).

To manually do that I use screen and then split once vertically (Ctrl-a + |) and then once horizontally (Ctrl-a + S). Finally I end with (Ctrl-a + TAB, Ctrl-a + c) to start the command line on the two new areas.
Is there a way to automate this with a bash script and using .bashrc ?
I am using xterm-256color in Ubuntu 22.04.

It perhaps could be done using screen, I'm personally not familiar with it beyond attaching / detaching sessions (apparently you can pass commands to a detached session using -X). So maybe start detached, pass commands, attach to the session. Unless you're on a confined environment (can't install software and the likes) you may also consider using tmux (it's meant to be an improvement over screen with lots of additional options, scripting stuff with it is often a breeze).

Using xterm. (I don't have xterm-256color installed but it should give you the idea).
Sorry in advance as I haven't followed your layout quite right.
Make a script directory and make three scripts xt1.sh, xt2.sh & xt3.sh
in xt1.sh add the following: -
#!/bin/bash
xterm -geometry 80x25+1+1

In xt2.sh add
#!/bin/bash
xterm -geometry 80x25+885+1

In xt3.sh add
#!/bin/bash
xterm -geometry 162x23+1+650

These are bought into existence with a fourth script called xt.sh
#!/bin/bash
./xt1.sh &
./xt2.sh &
./xt3.sh

You will need to make all four executable chmod 755 {filename}
Well it sort of fits on my display reasonably well. The & in the last script allows all three terminals to run at the same time. The {num}x{num} is the terminal geometry and the ...+{num}+{num} is the offsets. (They are not measures of the same quantity though.
There are all sort of other parameters you can add to each terminal.
You normally control xterm from the .Xresources file not .bashrc. These usually have default parameters in them and don't create processes as such which seems to be what you want.

Hi, I tried out your suggestion but with the scripts for xterm I end up having three separate windows.
